# Build up LINQ expression before querying

Tags: c#, sql, linq, expression

I'm querying data using LINQ to SQL, but I'd like to add to the expressions before I submit the query. So far, I have this:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null) where T : class
    {
        var table = GetTable<T>();
        return expression != null ? table.Where(expression).OrderBy("OrderBy") : table;
    }
```

If I wanted to change the expression, or add another Where or OrderBy, could I do that before I query the actual table? Something like this:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null) where T : class
    {
        var table = GetTable<T>();
        expression.Where(my1stWhereClause).Where(my2ndWhereClause);
        expression.OrderBy("my1stColumn");
        expression.ThenBy("my2ndColumn");
        return expression != null ? table.Where(expression) : table;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the code you provided?

Comment: @Maarten Usually when people provide code that looks like what they want to solve, it's just that - pseudocode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the return value from each method you call, like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null)
     where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> query = GetTable<T>();
    query = query.Where(my1stWhereClause).Where(my2ndWhereClause);
    // Doing this dynamically doesn't really work..
    query = expression.OrderBy(x => x.My1stColumn)
                      .ThenBy(x => x.My2ndColumn);
    return expression != null ? query.Where(expression) : query;
}
```

It's not really clear how you're expecting to have `my1stWhereClause` and `my2ndWhereClause` without knowing `T` beforehand... and in order to call `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`, you really need to know the type you're dealing with too.

However, the idea of building up a query like this is very much supported in LINQ - and even when you return it here, that's still not *executed* anything against the data source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This function will be part of my data framework used by other developers of the solution. So my idea is to allow people to pass in custom expressions with Dynamic LINQ (which would explain the explicit my2ndWhereClause). However, I still need to enforce certain rules on top of the expressions they provide, which is why I want to build the query up dynamically.

Comment: @drminnaar: Does Dynamic LINQ (which isn't mentioned anywhere in your question) work with LINQ to SQL? I don't know, as I haven't used it - but if it does, then I'd expect this approach to work.

Comment: It does. I've wrapped what you've given me with dynamic LINQ and it works flawlessly. Thanks again for your help.